# What classifier with Weka?

Tags: classification, weka

I look for a classifier with Weka for this problem :
An instance is a triolet (or more) of reals (or not) : x y and z. 
I know only the positives instances (so i can train).
Exemple : 
3.524, -4.529875, 3.6295626
2.7670588, -3.4611764, 6.03
3.878375, -4.47225, 4.6831875
4.6477776, -4.3755555, 3.6093333
3.8646667, -4.043389, 3.3882778

So, now i would like to create a classifier. It could say me if yes or no (with a probability in percent) a new instance is in this "same family".
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do supervised binary classification is to train classifiers with data from both classes. Although there are reports on training classifiers on positive data only, my experience is not so sweet. There is a huge difference between human labeled data for both classes and the process of automatic labeling of negative class data from the unlabelled data pool.

The approaches can be found [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfmhttp://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1401920&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=635635241&CFTOKEN=70144410) and [here](https://www.cs.iastate.edu/~yetianc/cs573/files/CS573_ProjectReport_YetianChen.pdf). But the approaches have limitations and my suggestions would be to label reasonable amount of negative data instances by experts. If this becomes too expensive then you can start with small negative data, apply semisupervised learning to increase negative data or use SMOTE to increase negative data synthetically. But again these have their own limitations.

Comment: Thanks again Rushdi, suppose i've negative instances as much as positive instances. Unfortunatly this negative datas are too different to have a good classifier. Can i say for a new instance ? : ok if you're positive, it's good (probability is over 0.5) but if you're not -> negative without another test. To summarize i want just use the probability to be positive.

Comment: Yes if you have the same feature values for negative instances as for positive values then it is doable. If the nature of positive and negative data is different then that is a quality question. But quantitatively it is very much doable.